# Redirect to external Url from MVC controller with attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to redirect to external url from an action method but can't get it to work. The url has some attributes and I need to pass it in the same format to the destination website. It is redirecting to the website but all the attributes (parameters) are removed once it is redirected. Here is code

```
public ActionResult Redirect()
{
    string url = "https://example.us.com/?t=b&id=100";
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

The resulted url in the destination website is like this https://example.us.com

Comment: Typically, it's a bad idea to use an HTTP 301 or 302 to redirect to an external URL. If you know ahead of time that you're going to redirect, do it via the `href` attribute of your link or via the `action` of your `form`.

Comment: So you are trying to redirect to `"https://example.us.com/?t=b&id=100"` but get redirected to `"https://example.us.com"` instead?

Comment: Are you by chance being redirect _by_ `https://example.us.com`? You can use your browser's dev tools (Network) to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class to get url information, there are two useful property  `uri.Scheme` contain is `http` or `https`, another property is `uri.Host` can get the domain name.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     string url = "https://example.us.com/?t=b&id=100";
     var uri = new Uri(url);
     var domainURL = string.Format("{0}://{1}",uri.Scheme, uri.Host);
     return Redirect(domainURL);
}
```

Comment: Did you want to remove all parameter when you go to the url?

Comment: @JJAbrm If you want to clear the parameter you can try my edit answer

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just passing the URL to Redirect?

```
public ActionResult Redirect()
{
  var url = "https://www.google.com";
  return Redirect(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @D-Shih answers, we could use the property "AbsoluteUri" to catch the whole Url only.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     string url = "https://example.us.com/?t=b&id=100";
     var uri = new Uri(url);

     return Redirect(uri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
public void Redirect()
{
    string url = "https://example.us.com/?t=b&id=100";
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

well this works for me. I was having similar issue.